# Clarification of the --save option for npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

First experiences with node.js/npm. From the *npm-install* docs I read:

`npm install` takes 3 exclusive, optional flags which save or update the package version in your main `package.json`:

- `--save`: Package will appear in your `dependencies`.
- `--save-dev`: Package will appear in your `devDependencies`.
- `--save-optional`: Package will appear in your `optionalDependencies`.

But I can't understand how it works in practice. If, for example, I run the command:

```
npm install bower --save-dev
```

I'd expect to find a `package.json` file in the current directory with `devDependencies` set to the installed version of bower, instead I find nothing.

Am I doing/expecting something wrong?

Using node v0.10.21, npm 1.3.12 on Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm` won't ***create*** `package.json` for you, but it ***will*** create the necessary dependencies for you as long as `package.json` **exists and is legal JSON**.

Create it like so

```
echo {} > package.json
```

Then, doing `npm i --save whatever` will add `whatever@~x.x.x` as a dependency as expected. The file needs to be there, and be JSON, that's it.

[image: npm.png]

Comment: `npm init` would be another options

Comment: What's your version? Because I just tried with `npm 1.2.21` and doesn't work for me.

Comment: Not working with latest `npm`. Nico is right. Will delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`npm install` only fetches the packages from the registry and puts them in your ./node_modules. It updates your package.json to register this new dependency if you tell it to.
Your package.json has three dependency blocks :

1. dependencies - these are needed for your app to run.
2. devDependencies - these are needed for the developer environments for your app (this is how your teammates can get the packages that you recently added to the project. The dependencies listed here are not required on production hosts.)
3. optionalDependencies - These packages are optional and it is OK if npm cant reolve the package to install. i.e a build failure does not cause npm install to fail (Note however, that your app should handle cases where the package cannot be found.)

Here is the behavior with the different usages of the npm install command:

```
$ npm install async #Only installs, no change made to package.json
$ npm install async --save #Installs, adds async@version to dependencies block
$ npm install async --save-dev # Installs, adds async@version to the devDependencies block
$ npm install async --save-optional # Installs, adds async@version to the optionalDependencies block
```