# NPM install with --save key

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning Node and still do not understand why should I use (or should not?) key `--save` or `--save-dev` event after reading https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.

Ok, I understood that there is `package.json` which appears after `npm init`. Am I really have to want this file?

Next, in this file there is couple of sections, like `dependencies` or `dependenciesDev`. I understand that last one specify modules used only when application developed. But why I should add something to `dependencies` section? For example, I want to use `react-loopback` but in documentation specified it should be installed without saving in dependencies (i.e. without `--save` key, just `npm install react-loopback`). Why?

Finally: how should I decide what to save in `package.json` and what - not to save?

Comment: You package.json allows you to specify all the dependencies your project has without actually providing them inside your code base. This is really helpful when using version control e.g. git or svn, because then you won't have to add those to your repository. Everyone cloning your project just has to execute "npm install" and should be good to go.

Comment: @puelo got it. But why some packages says it should be installed without saving in `dependencies`? Just missed this when documentation was writing? Or intentionally omitted?

Comment: The reason for not mentioning `--save` in the documentation could just be that they assume that the developers know about it themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clarification of the --save option for npm install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20902612/clarification-of-the-save-option-for-npm-install)

Answer (score 1):

`--save` is for your nodejs dependencies used as part of your app, `--save-dev` is used to load dev dependencies which are not part of app but are required at development time.

A good example of these are the `express` package is a app dependecy as it is needed as part of app while `gulp/ grunt` package is a dev dependency as it is needed for app development and build but not as part of your app

Answer (score 1):

When running `npm install --save` or `--save-dev`

- npm will save a copy of the npm package inside the **./node_modules/** directory
- npm will write the npm package name and version in **package.json**
- when your node app requires/imports that module in the code it will use the copy in **./node_modules/**. Otherwise it would keep looking recursively in parent directories.

---

**`npm install --save`**

Run `npm install --save` when it is a npm package you need on runtime for your node app. 
This would be useful when there are some deployment platforms like *Heroku* that will only install the **dependencies** listed on **package.json**. In this case you will have to send to *Heroku* the bundles already pre-built because it won't install the **devDependencies**.

eg. express, request, loggers

---

**`npm install --save-dev`**

Run `npm install --save-dev` for packages that you will use only in the build of a bundle of your client javascript file or tools you need for running unit tests, etc.

eg. React, eslint, mocha, babel

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I just a bit confuse with your mention of React among devDependencies. If it is not specified in `dependencies` it will be unavailable once application deployed to Heroku. Could you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: it would be available inside your **bundle.js** since the browser doesn't uses node_modules. The browser uses the bundle.js which contains all the npm packages you need for your single page app. 
In case you are using React to render on the server-side then you do need to include React in the *dependencies* since it will be used by your node app